# SQL Statement using WHERE with 2 lists depending on each other

Tags: mysql

I have 2 huge tables of products and specifications and let's say I need to get/update 40 of them. I am trying to use those lists like

`first list->row == second list->row`

My SQL looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM product JOIN specification ON product.id_product = spceification.product_id WHERE product.id_product IN (1592,1593,16062,1615)
 AND specification.suffix IN ('E-150','E-100','0-PLUS',NULL)
```

Now it returns so many results because some other products with different ID has this suffix. So I need only returns:

```
1592 + E-150,
1593 + E-100,
16062 + 0-PLUS,
1615 + NULL
```

Basically I need something like this (below) but I though I can do it with 2 lists (this solution below does not work either, it has some kind of error):

```
SELECT * FROM product JOIN specification.product_id = product.id_product WHERE 
(product.id_product = 1592 AND specification.suffix = E-150),
(product.id_product = 1593 AND specification.suffix = E-100),
...
```

If you understand me (sorry I have really bad english and explaining skills). Thank you for any tips!

Comment: The `,` in your `WHERE` clause should be `OR`, other than that it should work fine

Comment: Note that for your last case you will need to use `(product.id_product = 1615 AND specification.suffix IS NULL)`

Comment: Can you please give the column names instead of * so that i write query in a more better way. To be more specific only the column name for which the value will be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query is almost spot-on. You were very close there :)

Try changing the commas by OR

```
SELECT * FROM product JOIN specification.product_id = product.id_product WHERE 
(product.id_product = 1592 AND specification.suffix = E-150) OR
(product.id_product = 1593 AND specification.suffix = E-100)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below-

```
select * from 
(
SELECT * FROM product JOIN specification 
ON product.id_product = spceification.product_id 
WHERE product.id_product IN (1592,1593,16062,1615) AND specification.suffix IN ('E-150','E-100','0-PLUS',NULL)
)A WHERE (id_product, suffix) IN ( (1592 , 'E-150'), (1593 ,'E-100') )
```